# Many Threads_connected mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fixing an web application that uses PHP 5.4 and mySQL.

Sometimes the mySQL shows error "Too many connections", I have read about this error and I know it is important close connections after its use. 
I'm calling mysql_close() after all database operation, correctly apparently .

This application is used by many different people in many machines, so maybe too many connections is "normal", and all I have to do is increase max_connections variable.

My doubt is, when I do `show status like '%onn%'` the result is

[image: show status like '%onn%']
is that **Threads_connected** correct? 
They continues after mysql_close() call. My max_connections limit is 151, what means, 151 Threads connected? How is relation between thread connection and "Too many connections error". 
How I close these Threads?

Answer (score 0):

What are your clients?  What limits do they have?  If, for example, you are using Apache with MaxClients set to 200, then you could easily exceed 151.

Are the threads slow in completing?  If so, let's look at the slow queries and speed them up so they can release the connections sooner.

**Edit**

**Threads_running** is of more concern than **Threads_connected**.  The former is actually doing something; the latter includes threads in `Sleep` mode, as seen in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: I have many clients, true, but I want a way that the client doesn't hold the connection, you see in the image that are 57 threads connected, I want to have 0. Is true, when Threads_connected arrive at 151, "too many connections" error will be trowed?

Comment: It could be that the web server is hanging on to them even after mysql_close().  This is called "persistent connections".  Hence, my comment about Apache.  On another topic, mysql_* interface is deprecated; you should switch to mysqli_*.

Comment: Ok, but too many connections error happen because exists many threads_connected right? It's possible to close those threads?

Comment: Yes.  We need to find out why the _clients_ are connecting in droves and failing to disconnect.  What are you clients?

Comment: It's a simple PHP aplication, that are connected by many machines, around 20-70 machines. 
But in the most time, each application don't need mysql connection. In my opinion that threads_connected must be around of 2 or 3 connected at same time.

Comment: What is the web server?  If Apache, what is MaxClients?  Consider shrinking that.

Comment: Perhaps the PHP setup automatically has "persistent connections".  If so, there is likely not to be a problem.  You simply have lots of idle (`Sleep`) threads running.  Decrease `wait_timeout` in order to get them bumped off when the Sleep too long.

Comment: Web server is Apache, I will take a look in persistent connections. This is in php.ini ?

Comment: I have even not found a solution, any other idea?

Comment: MaxClients is in httpd.conf of some include file that that brings in.  I guess I am out of ideas.  :(